# Pyspark SQL: Keep entries with only null values in pivot table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table on a PySpark SQL dataframe, which doesn't drop the null values. My input table has the following structure:

[image: data]

I am running everything in the IBM Data Science Experience cloud under Python 2 with spark 2.1.

When doing it on a pandas dataframe the "dropna=false" parameter gives me the result I want.

```
table= pd.pivot_table(ratings,columns=['movieId'],index=[ 'monthyear','userId'], values='rating', dropna=False)
```

As an output I get the following:

[image: Pandas pivot result]

In PySpark SQL I am using at the moment the following command:

```
ratings_pivot = spark_df.groupBy('monthyear','userId').pivot('movieId').sum("rating").show()
```

As an output I get the following:

[image: PySpark pivot result]

As you can see, all the entries with only null values are not shown. Is there a possibility to use something similar like dropna=false in SQL? Since this is very specific, I can´t find anything about that in the internet.

I just extracted a small dataset for reproduction:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("1", 30, 2.5,200912), ("1", 32, 3.0,200912), ("2", 40, 4.0,201002), ("3", 45, 2.5,200002)], ("userID", "movieID", "rating", "monthyear"))
```

df.show()

```
+------+-------+------+---------+
|userID|movieID|rating|monthyear|
+------+-------+------+---------+
|     1|     30|   2.5|   200912|
|     1|     32|   3.0|   200912|
|     2|     40|   4.0|   201002|
|     3|     45|   2.5|   200002|
+------+-------+------+---------+
```

If I now run the pivot query, I get the following result:

```
df.groupBy("monthyear","UserID").pivot("movieID").sum("rating").show()

+---------+------+----+----+----+----+
|monthyear|UserID|  30|  32|  40|  45|
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+
|   201002|     2|null|null| 4.0|null|
|   200912|     1| 2.5| 3.0|null|null|
|   200002|     3|null|null|null| 2.5|
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+
```

What I want now, is that in the results looks like the following:

```
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+
|monthyear|UserID|  30|  32|  40|  45|
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+
|   201002|     2|null|null| 4.0|null|
|   200912|     2|null|null|null|null|
|   200002|     2|null|null|null|null|
|   200912|     1| 2.5| 3.0|null|null|
|   200002|     1|null|null|null|null|
|   201002|     1|null|null|null|null|
|   200002|     3|null|null|null| 2.5|
|   200912|     3|null|null|null|null|
|   201002|     3|null|null|null|null|
+---------+------+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I edited my question to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark provide anything like this, because it just won't scale. `pivot` alone is expensive enough. It can be done manually with outer join:

```py
n = 20 # Adjust value depending on the data

wide = (df
    # Get unique months
    .select("monthyear")
    .distinct()
    .coalesce(n)  # Coalesce to avoid partition number "explosion"
    # Same as above for UserID and get Cartesian product
    .crossJoin(df.select("UserID").distinct().coalesce(n))
    # Join with pivoted data
    .join(
        df.groupBy("monthyear", "UserID")
            .pivot("movieID")
            .sum("rating"),
        ["monthyear", "UserID"], 
        "leftouter"))
wide.show()

# +---------+------+----+----+----+----+
# |monthyear|UserID|  30|  32|  40|  45|
# +---------+------+----+----+----+----+
# |   201002|     3|null|null|null|null|
# |   201002|     2|null|null| 4.0|null|
# |   200002|     1|null|null|null|null|
# |   200912|     1| 2.5| 3.0|null|null|
# |   200002|     3|null|null|null| 2.5|
# |   200912|     2|null|null|null|null|
# |   200912|     3|null|null|null|null|
# |   201002|     1|null|null|null|null|
# |   200002|     2|null|null|null|null|
# +---------+------+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Spark does keep entries with all `null` values, for both rows and columns:

**Spark 2.1**:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.4 (default, Dec 21 2017 21:42:08)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

In [1]: df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1, 4), ("a", 2, 2), ("b", 3, None), (None, 4, None)], ("x", "y", "z"))

In [2]: df.groupBy("x").pivot("y").sum("z").show()
+----+----+----+----+----+                                                      
|   x|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|null|null|null|null|null|
|   b|null|null|null|null|
|   a|   4|   2|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**Spark 2.2**:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.4 (default, Dec 21 2017 21:42:08)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

In [1]: df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1, 4), ("a", 2, 2), ("b", 3, None), (None, 4, None)], ("x", "y", "z"))

In [2]: df.groupBy("x").pivot("y").sum("z").show()
+----+----+----+----+----+                                                      
|   x|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|null|null|null|null|null|
|   b|null|null|null|null|
|   a|   4|   2|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**Spark 2.3**:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.4 (default, Dec 21 2017 21:42:08)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

In [1]: df = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1, 4), ("a", 2, 2), ("b", 3, None), (None, 4, None)], ("x", "y", "z"))

In [2]: df.groupBy("x").pivot("y").sum("z").show()
+----+----+----+----+----+                                                      
|   x|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|null|null|null|null|null|
|   b|null|null|null|null|
|   a|   4|   2|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am using Spark version 2.1. I edited my question a bit in the last part to make it more clear.